# Is there a way to output View without buffering in Kohana?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana, buffering

(does the MVC archtecture support this ability in general?)

Comment: No, output buffering is not even part of the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Kohana::close_buffers()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot output a view line by line without buffering. Kohana uses an output buffer to capture the view as it is being rendered, then returns the output buffer as a string. You would have to overload `View::render()` with an extension or create your own class to bypass this.